# Simultaneous signing ceremonies in one envelope

Tags: php, session, docusignapi

I am using the DocuSign rest API to create two recipient envelope views. Each view is generated with a unique userName, email, clientUserId and recipientId and should be signed simultaneously. If the second view is created while the first signer is actively signing, the first signer will receive the following message:

[image: unable_to_finish_envelope_correction_in_progress]

The first recipient has to generate a brand new view in order to resume/complete their signing ceremony and everything works as expected after that (the second recipient is not kicked out).

The signers are accessing their own recipient views from separate machines. When I view the session information of each view, they each have unique recipient ID's, as expected.

Is it possible for both recipients/signers to be actively signing in the same envelope (separate views), at the same time, without one first getting kicked out?

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible, envelope is locked while someone is signing. This [blog post](https://www.docusign.com/blog/dsdev-common-api-tasks-locking-and-unlocking-envelopes/) explains how to lock and unlock envelopes.

Comment: Here is the referenced blog post: https://www.docusign.com/blog/dsdev-common-api-tasks-locking-and-unlocking-envelopes/

Answer (score 1):

You need to ensure that you only have one recipient signing view active at a time. Otherwise your signer will receive the error.

If your signers are sequential (different routing orders), then there's no problem since you can only create a recipient signing view for a signer with the envelope's current routing level.

If your signers are parallel (same routing order), then your app needs to create its own mutex.  You might be able to use the [envelope lock](https://www.docusign.com/blog/dsdev-common-api-tasks-locking-and-unlocking-envelopes/) as a mutex, I haven't tried it. (But also note that locking an envelope will probably cause an "Envelope correction event" in the certificate of completion.)